# MapKit not showing traffic using MKmapView

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, mkmapview

I am having a problem displaying `traffic` onto a `MKMapView`. 
When I open the iPhone `Maps` application the `traffic` is visible.

When using the MKMapView within an application, the traffic does not show.

> Start a new project, add a MKMapView to the storyboard and set
>       all the properties of the MKMapView to true using the `Attribute Inspector`:
>
> Type: Standard
>       Shows: Buildings, Compass, Scale, Traffic, Points of Interest, User Location

How do I get the traffic to show?

Is this an apple IOS bug?

**I am using Xcode 9.4.1 and IOS Version 11.4.1, iPhone 6S+**

*I have also subsequently loaded a MKMapView on an iPhone X,
and the traffic was showing for the "same" region. 
I am not sure of the IOS version though, and this was not the exact same
code base. I have also submitted a bug to Apple.*

Some sample code:

```
    import UIKit
    import MapKit
    import CoreLocation

    class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

        @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
        var manager =  CLLocationManager()

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            // add the some text to your plist entry: "Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description"  
            manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        }

        func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
            if status == CLAuthorizationStatus.authorizedWhenInUse || status == CLAuthorizationStatus.authorizedAlways {
                mapView.mapType = MKMapType.standard
                mapView.delegate = self
                mapView.showsTraffic = true
                mapView.showsUserLocation = true
                mapView.setUserTrackingMode(MKUserTrackingMode.followWithHeading, animated: true)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have found this radar, http://www.openradar.me/25854194
But it seems old - Date Originated: 2/25/17

Comment: Can someone please do some tests by creating "a sample app" and test on some devices - I only have one device with me at the moment.